# Can it be sticky to element higher up in the hierarchy?

Tags: css, svelte

I'm making a svelte-element inside this simplified structure:

```
<article>
  <div class="someDiv" />
  <section class="someSection" />
  <div class="someOtherDiv"/>
  <div id="thisShouldBeSticky">
      <div>SVELTE-ELEMENT<div/>
  </div>
</article>
```

How can I make the div holding the svelte-element sticky relative to `<article>`?

The svelte-component is a menu and I want it to stick to the top of the screen when the reader scrolls past it.

I know that an element with position:sticky only is sticky relative to its parent. But hoping there is a way to accomplish this?

EDIT:

Realize the structure above is to simplified. This is more relevant:

```
 <article>
      <div class="someDiv" />
      <section class="someSection" />
      <div class="someOtherDiv"/>
      <div id="someElement">
          <div class="Svelte-wrapper>
             <div class="ThisShouldBeSticky">SVELTE ELEMENT<div/>
          </div>
      </div>
    </article>
```

Answer (score 2):

Providing the parent element has `position: static;` (or no position style set at all) the sticky element will be stuck on the first relative/absolute ancestor that it encounters.

See the code below to show the sticky nature for `.ThisShouldBeSticky`

```css
article {
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: 600px;
}

.ThisShouldBeSticky {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

#someElement,
.Svelte-wrapper {
  display: contents;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <div class="someDiv">someDiv</div>
  <section class="someSection">someSection</section>
  <div class="someOtherDiv">someOtherDiv</div>
  <div id="someElement">
      <div class="Svelte-wrapper">
         <div class="ThisShouldBeSticky">SVELTE ELEMENT</div>
      </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: I edited my question realizing the example structure provided is to simplified. What makes this a bit more complex is that the svelte-component is a bit deeper down in the hierarchy.

Comment: @Tore I have updated my answer to work with your nested structure. You can use `display: contents;` to force the parent elements to be ignored in the structure: https://caniuse.com/css-display-contents

Comment: Thank you. I actually found a working solution where I just set #someElement, onMount of the svelte-component, to be sticky. It works since its not holding any other content but the parent of the svelte-element, but your suggestion might be better. Will check it out.